# How to add symbol to end of <Link> component from Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hyperlink

How do I add a symbol (e.g. >) to the end of a  component from Material UI? i.e. It looks like this:

[image]

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
<Link>
   Learn more &gt;
</Link>
```

But I want it to end up looking like this without adding ">" into the HTML:

```
<Link xxx>
   Learn more
</Link>
```

Comment: what if you put it in a variable and then put that variable in link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do it like this

```
return (
    <Link>
        Learn More {">"}
    </Link>
);
```

If you want it to not be underlined, I would put it in its own tag and make the css to that tag be disabled

```
return (
     <Link>
         Learn More <p className="myParagraph">{">"}</p>
     <Link>
);
```

css file:

```
myParagraph {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
const linkSymbol = ">";

return ( 
  <Link props> 
     Learn More {linkSymbol}
  </Link>
)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want the ">" symbol to be underlined when the cursor hovers over it. You can refer to my edited post for a more visual representation. Thanks!